# How would you shorten this long winded if/elif function?

Tags: python, if-statement

This code works as intended but is not very elegant. I am looking for different perspectives or better methods of getting the same result. Also if you have any recommendations for naming conventions when it comes to variables for code readability, feedback is welcome.

```
def get_oldest(date1, date2):
    """Given 2 date strings in "MM/DD/YYYY" format, return oldest one."""
    date_one = date1.split("/")
    date_two = date2.split("/")
    if date_one[2] < date_two[2]:
        return date1
    elif date_one[2] > date_two[2]:
        return date2
    elif date_one[2] == date_two[2]:
        if date_one[0] < date_two[0]:
            return date1
        elif date_one[0] > date_two[0]:
            return date2
        elif date_one[0] == date_two[0]:
            if date_one[1] < date_two[1]:
                return date1
            elif date_one[1] > date_two[1]:
                return date2
            elif date_one[1] == date_two[1]:
                return date1


get_oldest("06/21/1958", "06/24/1958")
```

Comment: Questions asking for review of working code are better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. That said, why not parse your strings as dates and then simply compare the dates instead?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Thank You for the suggestion I was unaware of the code review section. I will post their as well. In this specific case, the professor explicitly said not to use any modules that analyze dates.

Comment: Consider a small function to reparse your input dates to an integer such as mm/dd/yyyy to yyyymmdd and simply use a sort algorithm to rearrange as required and simply reconstruct your date input from the 'integer'

Comment: @JasonChia Thank you for the suggestion. This is what I have done and have it working! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Use a sane date format. `mm/dd/yyyy` is not a sane date format.

Step 2: Use the built-in `min()` function.

There is no step 3.

```
min(["1958-06-21", "1958-06-24"])
```

`min()` expects a list of values. That list can be 1-N items long. It works well for your case (the smallest of two values), but any other case works just as well.

Comment: I restructured the date format and have it working now! Thank you!

Comment: @Jack Take-away: You will save yourself a huge headache when you never use localized date formats in in code. Always use the ISO date format, or [*actual* date data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to store and transfer dates. You can always produce localized formats like `mm/dd/yyyy` easily with [standard date formatting functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime), but you should only use those formats for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to use the built-in [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library?

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_oldest(date1, date2):
    date_one = datetime.strptime(date1, "%m/%d/%Y")
    date_two = datetime.strptime(date2, "%m/%d/%Y")
    if date_one < date_two:
        return date_one
    else:
        return date_two

print(get_oldest("06/21/1958", "06/24/1958"))
print(get_oldest("01/23/2005", "12/31/2004"))
```

Returns

```
1958-06-21 00:00:00
2004-12-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: FWIW, you could use `min()` as well: `return min([date_one, date_two])`